# noUISlider typeerror: a is null

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nouislider

I am trying to add - [noUISlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) via a `Wordpress` plugin. But when adding `nouislider.min.js` file via `enqueue` script, I get following error -

```
TypeError: a is null
```

Here is the `nouislider.min.js` where error is occurring -

```js
/*! nouislider - 8.0.2 - 2015-07-06 13:22:09 */

!function(a){if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],a);else if("object"==typeof exports){var b=require("fs");module.exports=a(),module.exports.css=function(){return b.readFileSync(__dirname+"/nouislider.min.css","utf8")}}else window.noUiSlider=a()}(function(){"use strict";function a(a){return a.filter(function(a){return this[a]?!1:this[a]=!0},{})}function b(a,b){return Math.round(a/b)*b}function c(a){var b=a.getBoundingClientRect(),c=a.ownerDocument,d=c.defaultView||c.parentWindow,e=c.documentElement,f=d.pageXOffset;return/webkit.*Chrome.*Mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(f=0),{top:b.top+d.pageYOffset-e.clientTop,left:b.left+f-e.clientLeft}}function d(a){return"number"==typeof a&&!isNaN(a)&&isFinite(a)}function e(a){var b=Math.pow(10,7);return Number((Math.round(a*b)/b).toFixed(7))}function f(a,b,c){j(a,b),setTimeout(function(){k(a,b)},c)}function g(a){return Math.max(Math.min(a,100),0)}function h(a){return Array.isArray(a)?a:[a]}function i(a){var b=a.split(".");return b.length>1?b[1].length:0}function j(a,b){a.classList?a.classList.add(b):a.className+=" "+b}function k(a,b){a.classList?a.classList.remove(b):a.className=a.className.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\b)"+b.split(" ").join("|")+"(\\b|$)","gi")," ")}function l(a,b){a.classList?a.classList.contains(b):new RegExp("(^| )"+b+"( |$)","gi").test(a.className)}function m(a,b){return 100/(b-a)}function n(a,b){return 100*b/(a[1]-a[0])}function o(a,b){return n(a,a[0]<0?b+Math.abs(a[0]):b-a[0])}function p(a,b){return b*(a[1]-a[0])/100+a[0]}function q(a,b){for(var c=1;a>=b[c];)c+=1;return c}function r(a,b,c){if(c>=a.slice(-1)[0])return 100;var d,e,f,g,h=q(c,a);return d=a[h-1],e=a[h],f=b[h-1],g=b[h],f+o([d,e],c)/m(f,g)}function s(a,b,c){if(c>=100)return a.slice(-1)[0];var d,e,f,g,h=q(c,b);return d=a[h-1],e=a[h],f=b[h-1],g=b[h],p([d,e],(c-f)*m(f,g))}function t(a,c,d,e){if(100===e)return e;var f,g,h=q(e,a);return d?(f=a[h-1],g=a[h],e-f>(g-f)/2?g:f):c[h-1]?a[h-1]+b(e-a[h-1],c[h-1]):e}function u(a,b,c){var e;if("number"==typeof b&&(b=[b]),"[object Array]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(b))throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'range' contains invalid value.");if(e="min"===a?0:"max"===a?100:parseFloat(a),!d(e)||!d(b[0]))throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'range' value isn't numeric.");c.xPct.push(e),c.xVal.push(b[0]),e?c.xSteps.push(isNaN(b[1])?!1:b[1]):isNaN(b[1])||(c.xSteps[0]=b[1])}function v(a,b,c){return b?void(c.xSteps[a]=n([c.xVal[a],c.xVal[a+1]],b)/m(c.xPct[a],c.xPct[a+1])):!0}function w(a,b,c,d){this.xPct=[],this.xVal=[],this.xSteps=[d||!1],this.xNumSteps=[!1],this.snap=b,this.direction=c;var e,f=[];for(e in a)a.hasOwnProperty(e)&&f.push([a[e],e]);for(f.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]}),e=0;e<f.length;e++)u(f[e][1],f[e][0],this);for(this.xNumSteps=this.xSteps.slice(0),e=0;e<this.xNumSteps.length;e++)v(e,this.xNumSteps[e],this)}function x(a,b){if(!d(b))throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'step' is not numeric.");a.singleStep=b}function y(a,b){if("object"!=typeof b||Array.isArray(b))throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'range' is not an object.");if(void 0===b.min||void 0===b.max)throw new Error("noUiSlider: Missing 'min' or 'max' in 'range'.");a.spectrum=new w(b,a.snap,a.dir,a.singleStep)}function z(a,b){if(b=h(b),!Array.isArray(b)||!b.length||b.length>2)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'start' option is incorrect.");a.handles=b.length,a.start=b}function A(a,b){if(a.snap=b,"boolean"!=typeof b)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'snap' option must be a boolean.")}function B(a,b){if(a.animate=b,"boolean"!=typeof b)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'animate' option must be a boolean.")}function C(a,b){if("lower"===b&&1===a.handles)a.connect=1;else if("upper"===b&&1===a.handles)a.connect=2;else if(b===!0&&2===a.handles)a.connect=3;else{if(b!==!1)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'connect' option doesn't match handle count.");a.connect=0}}function D(a,b){switch(b){case"horizontal":a.ort=0;break;case"vertical":a.ort=1;break;default:throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'orientation' option is invalid.")}}function E(a,b){if(!d(b))throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'margin' option must be numeric.");if(a.margin=a.spectrum.getMargin(b),!a.margin)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'margin' option is only supported on linear sliders.")}function F(a,b){if(!d(b))throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'limit' option must be numeric.");if(a.limit=a.spectrum.getMargin(b),!a.limit)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'limit' option is only supported on linear sliders.")}function G(a,b){switch(b){case"ltr":a.dir=0;break;case"rtl":a.dir=1,a.connect=[0,2,1,3][a.connect];break;default:throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'direction' option was not recognized.")}}function H(a,b){if("string"!=typeof b)throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'behaviour' must be a string containing options.");var c=b.indexOf("tap")>=0,d=b.indexOf("drag")>=0,e=b.indexOf("fixed")>=0,f=b.indexOf("snap")>=0;a.events={tap:c||f,drag:d,fixed:e,snap:f}}function I(a,b){if(a.format=b,"function"==typeof b.to&&"function"==typeof b.from)return!0;throw new Error("noUiSlider: 'format' requires 'to' and 'from' methods.")}function J(a){var b,c={margin:0,limit:0,animate:!0,format:U};b={step:{r:!1,t:x},start:{r:!0,t:z},connect:{r:!0,t:C},direction:{r:!0,t:G},snap:{r:!1,t:A},animate:{r:!1,t:B},range:{r:!0,t:y},orientation:{r:!1,t:D},margin:{r:!1,t:E},limit:{r:!1,t:F},behaviour:{r:!0,t:H},format:{r:!1,t:I}};var d={connect:!1,direction:"ltr",behaviour:"tap",orientation:"horizontal"};return Object.keys(d).forEach(function(b){void 0===a[b]&&(a[b]=d[b])}),Object.keys(b).forEach(function(d){var e=b[d];if(void 0===a[d]){if(e.r)throw new Error("noUiSlider: '"+d+"' is required.");return!0}e.t(c,a[d])}),c.pips=a.pips,c.style=c.ort?"top":"left",c}function K(a,b,c){var d=a+b[0],e=a+b[1];return c?(0>d&&(e+=Math.abs(d)),e>100&&(d-=e-100),[g(d),g(e)]):[d,e]}function L(a){a.preventDefault();var b,c,d=0===a.type.indexOf("touch"),e=0===a.type.indexOf("mouse"),f=0===a.type.indexOf("pointer"),g=a;return 0===a.type.indexOf("MSPointer")&&(f=!0),d&&(b=a.changedTouches[0].pageX,c=a.changedTouches[0].pageY),(e||f)&&(b=a.clientX+window.pageXOffset,c=a.clientY+window.pageYOffset),g.points=[b,c],g.cursor=e||f,g}function M(a,b){var c=document.createElement("div"),d=document.createElement("div"),e=["-lower","-upper"];return a&&e.reverse(),j(d,T[3]),j(d,T[3]+e[b]),j(c,T[2]),c.appendChild(d),c}function N(a,b,c){switch(a){case 1:j(b,T[7]),j(c[0],T[6]);break;case 3:j(c[1],T[6]);case 2:j(c[0],T[7]);case 0:j(b,T[6])}}function O(a,b,c){var d,e=[];for(d=0;a>d;d+=1)e.push(c.appendChild(M(b,d)));return e}function P(a,b,c){j(c,T[0]),j(c,T[8+a]),j(c,T[4+b]);var d=document.createElement("div");return j(d,T[1]),c.appendChild(d),d}function Q(b,d){function e(a,b,c){if("range"===a||"steps"===a)return M.xVal;if("count"===a){var d,e=100/(b-1),f=0;for(b=[];(d=f++*e)<=100;)b.push(d);a="positions"}return"positions"===a?b.map(function(a){return M.fromStepping(c?M.getStep(a):a)}):"values"===a?c?b.map(function(a){return M.fromStepping(M.getStep(M.toStepping(a)))}):b:void 0}function m(b,c,d){var e=M.direction,f={},g=M.xVal[0],h=M.xVal[M.xVal.length-1],i=!1,j=!1,k=0;return M.direction=0,d=a(d.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})),d[0]!==g&&(d.unshift(g),i=!0),d[d.length-1]!==h&&(d.push(h),j=!0),d.forEach(function(a,e){var g,h,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t=a,u=d[e+1];if("steps"===c&&(g=M.xNumSteps[e]),g||(g=u-t),t!==!1&&void 0!==u)for(h=t;u>=h;h+=g){for(m=M.toStepping(h),n=m-k,q=n/b,r=Math.round(q),s=n/r,l=1;r>=l;l+=1)o=k+l*s,f[o.toFixed(5)]=["x",0];p=d.indexOf(h)>-1?1:"steps"===c?2:0,!e&&i&&(p=0),h===u&&j||(f[m.toFixed(5)]=[h,p]),k=m}}),M.direction=e,f}function n(a,b,c){function e(a){return["-normal","-large","-sub"][a]}function f(a,b,c){return'class="'+b+" "+b+"-"+h+" "+b+e(c[1])+'" style="'+d.style+": "+a+'%"'}function g(a,d){M.direction&&(a=100-a),d[1]=d[1]&&b?b(d[0],d[1]):d[1],i.innerHTML+="<div "+f(a,"noUi-marker",d)+"></div>",d[1]&&(i.innerHTML+="<div "+f(a,"noUi-value",d)+">"+c.to(d[0])+"</div>")}var h=["horizontal","vertical"][d.ort],i=document.createElement("div");return j(i,"noUi-pips"),j(i,"noUi-pips-"+h),Object.keys(a).forEach(function(b){g(b,a[b])}),i}function o(a){var b=a.mode,c=a.density||1,d=a.filter||!1,f=a.values||!1,g=a.stepped||!1,h=e(b,f,g),i=m(c,b,h),j=a.format||{to:Math.round};return I.appendChild(n(i,d,j))}function p(){return G["offset"+["Width","Height"][d.ort]]}function q(a,b){void 0!==b&&(b=Math.abs(b-d.dir)),Object.keys(R).forEach(function(c){var d=c.split(".")[0];a===d&&R[c].forEach(function(a){a(h(B()),b,r(Array.prototype.slice.call(Q)))})})}function r(a){return 1===a.length?a[0]:d.dir?a.reverse():a}function s(a,b,c,e){var f=function(b){return I.hasAttribute("disabled")?!1:l(I,T[14])?!1:(b=L(b),a===S.start&&void 0!==b.buttons&&b.buttons>1?!1:(b.calcPoint=b.points[d.ort],void c(b,e)))},g=[];return a.split(" ").forEach(function(a){b.addEventListener(a,f,!1),g.push([a,f])}),g}function t(a,b){var c,d,e=b.handles||H,f=!1,g=100*(a.calcPoint-b.start)/p(),h=e[0]===H[0]?0:1;if(c=K(g,b.positions,e.length>1),f=y(e[0],c[h],1===e.length),e.length>1){if(f=y(e[1],c[h?0:1],!1)||f)for(d=0;d<b.handles.length;d++)q("slide",d)}else f&&q("slide",h)}function u(a,b){var c=G.getElementsByClassName(T[15]),d=b.handles[0]===H[0]?0:1;c.length&&k(c[0],T[15]),a.cursor&&(document.body.style.cursor="",document.body.removeEventListener("selectstart",document.body.noUiListener));var e=document.documentElement;e.noUiListeners.forEach(function(a){e.removeEventListener(a[0],a[1])}),k(I,T[12]),q("set",d),q("change",d)}function v(a,b){var c=document.documentElement;if(1===b.handles.length&&(j(b.handles[0].children[0],T[15]),b.handles[0].hasAttribute("disabled")))return!1;a.stopPropagation();var d=s(S.move,c,t,{start:a.calcPoint,handles:b.handles,positions:[J[0],J[H.length-1]]}),e=s(S.end,c,u,{handles:b.handles});if(c.noUiListeners=d.concat(e),a.cursor){document.body.style.cursor=getComputedStyle(a.target).cursor,H.length>1&&j(I,T[12]);var f=function(){return!1};document.body.noUiListener=f,document.body.addEventListener("selectstart",f,!1)}}function w(a){var b,e,g=a.calcPoint,h=0;return a.stopPropagation(),H.forEach(function(a){h+=c(a)[d.style]}),b=h/2>g||1===H.length?0:1,g-=c(G)[d.style],e=100*g/p(),d.events.snap||f(I,T[14],300),H[b].hasAttribute("disabled")?!1:(y(H[b],e),q("slide",b),q("set",b),q("change",b),void(d.events.snap&&v(a,{handles:[H[h]]})))}function x(a){var b,c;if(!a.fixed)for(b=0;b<H.length;b+=1)s(S.start,H[b].children[0],v,{handles:[H[b]]});a.tap&&s(S.start,G,w,{handles:H}),a.drag&&(c=[G.getElementsByClassName(T[7])[0]],j(c[0],T[10]),a.fixed&&c.push(H[c[0]===H[0]?1:0].children[0]),c.forEach(function(a){s(S.start,a,v,{handles:H})}))}function y(a,b,c){var e=a!==H[0]?1:0,f=J[0]+d.margin,h=J[1]-d.margin,i=J[0]+d.limit,l=J[1]-d.limit;return H.length>1&&(b=e?Math.max(b,f):Math.min(b,h)),c!==!1&&d.limit&&H.length>1&&(b=e?Math.min(b,i):Math.max(b,l)),b=M.getStep(b),b=g(parseFloat(b.toFixed(7))),b===J[e]?!1:(a.style[d.style]=b+"%",a.previousSibling||(k(a,T[17]),b>50&&j(a,T[17])),J[e]=b,Q[e]=M.fromStepping(b),q("update",e),!0)}function z(a,b){var c,e,f;for(d.limit&&(a+=1),c=0;a>c;c+=1)e=c%2,f=b[e],null!==f&&f!==!1&&("number"==typeof f&&(f=String(f)),f=d.format.from(f),(f===!1||isNaN(f)||y(H[e],M.toStepping(f),c===3-d.dir)===!1)&&q("update",e))}function A(a){var b,c,e=h(a);for(d.dir&&d.handles>1&&e.reverse(),d.animate&&-1!==J[0]&&f(I,T[14],300),b=H.length>1?3:1,1===e.length&&(b=1),z(b,e),c=0;c<H.length;c++)q("set",c)}function B(){var a,b=[];for(a=0;a<d.handles;a+=1)b[a]=d.format.to(Q[a]);return r(b)}function C(){T.forEach(function(a){a&&k(I,a)}),I.innerHTML="",delete I.noUiSlider}function D(){var a=J.map(function(a,b){var c=M.getApplicableStep(a),d=i(String(c[2])),e=Q[b],f=100===a?null:c[2],g=Number((e-c[2]).toFixed(d)),h=0===a?null:g>=c[1]?c[2]:c[0]||!1;return[h,f]});return r(a)}function E(a,b){R[a]=R[a]||[],R[a].push(b),"update"===a.split(".")[0]&&H.forEach(function(a,b){q("update",b)})}function F(a){var b=a.split(".")[0],c=a.substring(b.length);Object.keys(R).forEach(function(a){var d=a.split(".")[0],e=a.substring(d.length);b&&b!==d||c&&c!==e||delete R[a]})}var G,H,I=b,J=[-1,-1],M=d.spectrum,Q=[],R={};if(I.noUiSlider)throw new Error("Slider was already initialized.");return G=P(d.dir,d.ort,I),H=O(d.handles,d.dir,G),N(d.connect,I,H),x(d.events),d.pips&&o(d.pips),{destroy:C,steps:D,on:E,off:F,get:B,set:A}}function R(a,b){if(!a.nodeName)throw new Error("noUiSlider.create requires a single element.");var c=J(b,a),d=Q(a,c);d.set(c.start),a.noUiSlider=d}var S=window.navigator.pointerEnabled?{start:"pointerdown",move:"pointermove",end:"pointerup"}:window.navigator.msPointerEnabled?{start:"MSPointerDown",move:"MSPointerMove",end:"MSPointerUp"}:{start:"mousedown touchstart",move:"mousemove touchmove",end:"mouseup touchend"},T=["noUi-target","noUi-base","noUi-origin","noUi-handle","noUi-horizontal","noUi-vertical","noUi-background","noUi-connect","noUi-ltr","noUi-rtl","noUi-dragable","","noUi-state-drag","","noUi-state-tap","noUi-active","","noUi-stacking"];w.prototype.getMargin=function(a){return 2===this.xPct.length?n(this.xVal,a):!1},w.prototype.toStepping=function(a){return a=r(this.xVal,this.xPct,a),this.direction&&(a=100-a),a},w.prototype.fromStepping=function(a){return this.direction&&(a=100-a),e(s(this.xVal,this.xPct,a))},w.prototype.getStep=function(a){return this.direction&&(a=100-a),a=t(this.xPct,this.xSteps,this.snap,a),this.direction&&(a=100-a),a},w.prototype.getApplicableStep=function(a){var b=q(a,this.xPct),c=100===a?2:1;return[this.xNumSteps[b-2],this.xVal[b-c],this.xNumSteps[b-c]]},w.prototype.convert=function(a){return this.getStep(this.toStepping(a))};var U={to:function(a){return a.toFixed(2)},from:Number};return{create:R}});
```

Comment: Please post the script where you use the slider and try to unenqueue all other js scripts that might cause issues. Also you dont need to open two posts for the same topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952423/javascript-conflict-with-nouislider-in-wordpress-plugin)